# Filter DataFrame according to different columns combinations to be used for filter

Tags: python, pandas

Example of my CSV:

```
open_local_data,country,competition,match_id,match_name,market_id,market_name,runner_id,runner_name,status,total_matched,odds,market_matched,percentage,above_odds,result,back,lay
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684262,Uruguay Montevideo FC v Progreso,1.202440748,Match Odds,11076801,Uruguay Montevideo FC,OPEN,197.2,2.88,448.52,43.96682422188531,9.24460199966309,WINNER,1.7578,-1
2022-08-24 15:00:00,AT,Austrian Matches,31685733,SV Gerasdorf Stammersdorf v Dinamo Helfort,1.202453470,Match Odds,10299781,SV Gerasdorf Stammersdorf,OPEN,15.99,3.05,27.12,58.96017699115043,26.17329174524879,LOSER,-1,0.45609756097560983
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684267,Villa Espanola v Sud America,1.202440560,Match Odds,58805,The Draw,OPEN,458.35,3.5,651.11,70.39517132281796,41.82374275138939,LOSER,-1,0.37400000000000005
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684266,Miramar Misiones v Central Espanol,1.202440654,Match Odds,5300627,Miramar Misiones,OPEN,642.05,2.1,1075.66,59.68893516538684,12.069887546339224,LOSER,-1,0.85
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684266,Miramar Misiones v Central Espanol,1.202440654,Match Odds,5330852,Central Espanol,OPEN,356.65,4.5,1075.66,33.1563877061525,10.93416548393028,LOSER,-1,0.2671428571428571
2022-08-24 15:00:00,BR,Brazilian U20,31688169,Santa Cruz FC U20 v Retro U20,1.202492350,Match Odds,12819986,Santa Cruz FC U20,OPEN,74.82,2.18,78.72999999999999,95.03365934205512,49.16209970902761,LOSER,-1,0.7923728813559321
2022-08-24 15:00:00,CH,Swiss 1 Liga Promotion,31684279,Etoile Carouge v SC Bruhl St Gallen,1.202455897,Match Odds,544529,Etoile Carouge,OPEN,108.24,1.98,169.58999999999995,63.82451795506812,13.319467450017612,WINNER,0.9163,-1
2022-08-24 15:00:00,CH,Swiss 1 Liga Promotion,31684279,Etoile Carouge v SC Bruhl St Gallen,1.202455897,Match Odds,21005121,SC Bruhl St Gallen,OPEN,57.21,3.75,169.58999999999995,33.734300371484174,7.067633704817506,LOSER,-1,0.34
```

When I want to filter the lines that have the same data as the first line and I know which columns to use to filter the DataFrame, I can find the final result this way:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('history_p&l.csv')

def results(a,b):
    filter = df[
        (df['percentage'] == a) & 
        (df['odds'] == b)
    ]
    back_sum = filter['back'].sum()
    print(back_sum)

results(
    df.iloc[0]['percentage'],
    df.iloc[0]['odds']
)
```

But currently I want to discover the result for all possible combinations of columns with values in the DataFrame, in this case these are the options and this is how I create the list of possible combinations:

```python
def combs(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return [[]]
    cs = []
    for c in combs(a[1:]):
        cs += [c, c+[a[0]]]
    return cs

options = [
    'country',
    'competition',
    'match_id',
    'match_name',
    'market_id',
    'market_name',
    'runner_id',
    'runner_name',
    'total_matched',
    'odds',
    'market_matched',
    'percentage',
    'above_odds'
]

combinations = combs(options)
```

How can I manage to make my function (`def results()`) malleable to analyze the result for each of the combinations?

Also wondering how I will be able to call the function according to the different amount of arguments.

Note: I thought about using `eval()` and creating the code from strings, but I know that this is not indicated and is not smart to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `filter` you can dynamically build a predicate according to a single `combination` in `combinations` along the following lines

```
filter = df[reduce(lambda x, y : x & (df[y[0]] == y[1]), zip(combination, map(lambda x: df.iloc[0][x], combination)), True)]
```

Not sure what the best argument(s) for the `results()` would be but it depends on use cases. For example, `results()` could be called with just `combination` rather than `a, b`, or with two sequences: `combination` and the corresponding values.

Comment: Hello radof, I tried to do some tests, but all the options used in combination such as ```['competition']```, but it always generates a empty DataFrame, for example ```Series([], Name: competition, dtype: bool)```

Comment: @DigitalFarmer Oops, I have forgotten to filter the dataFrame with the predicate. The predicate is in fact a bool series with the same index as the dataFrame. Corrected.

Comment: Hi @radof ```UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.``` when using this method, I end up receiving this alert and when trying to adjust it so that it does not happen, I ended up not being successful, if possible to keep the answer updated, help me to create an option that does not end into this message, please. Tks

Comment: @DigitalFarmer I don't get this warning with the above filtering. Can you post a complete reproducible example for your problem? The warning means that the index of the dataframe does not match the index of the Boolean Series. For example, applying the filtering for the second time might result in this Warning in which case the behaviour might be non-deterministic.